# Karate: test upload doc with scenario outline

Tags: karate

I would like to test an end-point that allows me to download a pdf document.
For this I have several ways to test:

- I download a document < 2 mega (OK test)
- I download a document that is too large  > 2 mega (KO)
- I download a document in the wrong way (jpeg for example KO)

I would like to know if I can create a table that contains different documents to test

I would like to do something like this:

```
Scenario Outline:

  * myflile =
    """
    {
      file: "<docPdf>"
    }
    """

  Given path 'mypath'
  And request myFile
  And header Accept = 'application/json'
  When method post
  Then status 200

  Examples:
    | docPdf  |
    | goodDoc.dff  |
    | badDoc.pdf |
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well why not. Won't the below work:

```
* request read(docPdf)
```

Comment: So it’s not possible?

Comment: @ArnaudMichel it is possible

Answer (score 1):

ok I managed to implement my test cases with document upload. Here is my example which is very basic:

```
# upload doc------------------------------------------------
Given url azertyUrl
And path 'test'
And multipart file file = { read: <pdfDoc> }
When method post
Then status <status>

Examples:
  | pdfDoc | status |
  | test-pdf-down-2mega.pdf | 201 |
  | test-pdf-up-to-2mega.pdf | 413 |
```

However I do not know if it is possible to continue with other tests like this in the same scenario

```
# upload doc------------------------------------------------
Given url azertyUrl
And path 'test'
And multipart file file = { read: <pdfDoc> }
When method post
Then status <status>

Examples:
  | pdfDoc | status |
  | test-pdf-down-2mega.pdf | 201 |
  | test-pdf-up-to-2mega.pdf | 413 |

  * def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
  * def retrieveDocId = call read('classpath:karate/karate-utils.feature')
  * def docId = retrieveDocId.retrieveDocId(location)


    Given url azertyUrl
    And path 'test'
    And request signer
    When method post
    Then status 201

    * def signerId = response.id
```

By doing this I recover the following error

[image]

Comment: that error is clearly because your feature file is malformed. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue